# Tracing invoker of a systemd service

Tags: fedora, dbus, systemd

I'm having trouble with a bug in Fedora 24 Server edition. Firewalld service always starts even when it's disabled. On workstation however, it stays disabled as expected.

I looked it up and someone has encountered this bug as well:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1371122

According to one of the comments, a service can be started if other dbus client requests it. So my best shot is that some other software in Server edition starts Firewalld, which might be a management program? No idea. I guessed it was cockpit so I erased it with dnf but it wasn't the answer.

I'll be reporting this bug after I write this post. I wanna trace what/who starts the service. `systemctl list-dependencies` shows nothing. It says that Firewalld isn't even a dependency of other unit.

Comment: A little off the topic, but can you clarify why you want to disable firewalld? I'm collecting use cases.

Comment: @mattdm firewall setting is tedious for a server within a secure/private network (in my case, a network that's not even connected to the internet). And technicians are dumb/lazy af and don't even know how to linux. You know what I mean.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to mask a unit. I'm just baffled by the fact that I can disable it on Workstation. Much consistency, so simplicity.

Comment: Does it not stay disabled if you mask it?

Comment: @mattdm It does! What do you want from me? That's not what I'm asking here.

Comment: Well, as a practical matter, why not just mask it and move on? The question is still interesting from a diagnostic point of view, since it's useful to have a better picture of what's causing dbus activations, but if you just want it to not start, that's the easy answer.

Comment: `./rolekit.service
Requires=firewalld.service`

Answer (score 2):

Few things you can do. Your service might have started with a systemd dependency. Quite easy to figure it out. Just execute `systemd show FIREWALLD.service` and look for `WantedBy=` or `RequiredBy=`. If no one wants your service, then it is very likely started over dbus through dbus activation. You can run `busctl` and find if your service is a dbus activateable service.

Ex:

```
org.freedesktop.hostname1- - - (activatable) - -
```

If your service is being started through dbus activation, AFAIK, there is no easy way to find this out [1].

What you can do is you can mask the dbus service with `systemctl mask` and wait until for an error message from the application trying to talk to your FIREWALD.

[1] - I needed this information and I hacked in to dbus code. I have a patch that was working 1-2 years ago. If needed, try to apply this patch to dbus and rerun your system.

```
commit e1c687c96c36b7bbf2db33e967741c22fe7007c9
Author: Umut Tezduyar Lindskog <umuttl@axis.com>
Date:   Mon Sep 22 11:13:37 2014 +0200

    log originator of activation requests

diff --git a/dbus/bus/activation.c b/dbus/bus/activation.c
index 149cca8..2a9c0bd 100644
--- a/dbus/bus/activation.c
+++ b/dbus/bus/activation.c
@@ -1788,6 +1788,28 @@ bus_activation_activate_service (BusActivation  *activation,
   if (connection)
     dbus_connection_ref (connection);

+
+{
+DBusString loginfo_buf;
+unsigned long pid;
+// When connection is NULL, it is that we are trying to activate systemd
+// dbus[1106]: [system] Umut activation request by ':1.5' '/usr/bin/depd -n '
+// dbus[1106]: [system] Activating systemd to hand-off: service name='com.axis.Event.Switch' unit='dbus-com.axis.Event.Switch.service'
+if (connection != NULL && dbus_connection_get_unix_process_id (connection, &pid) && _dbus_string_init (&loginfo_buf))
+{
+  if (_dbus_command_for_pid (pid, &loginfo_buf, 50, NULL))
+  {
+    bus_context_log (activation->context,
+                   DBUS_SYSTEM_LOG_INFO, "Umut activation request by '%s' '%s'",
+                   bus_connection_get_name(connection), _dbus_string_get_const_data(&loginfo_buf));
+
+    _dbus_string_free (&loginfo_buf);
+  }
+
+}
+}
+
+
```

Comment: Good point. I should mask the service and look at the journal to see what pukes the error.

Comment: Or the mediocre could stay in silence. The search will continue then.